# How to send parallel HTTP POST requests in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

I'm trying to generate multiple requests and send it parallel to a server based on a concurrency factor. I'm relatively new to the multithreading world so I have come up with some code that does the work. I see that the total time to complete this operation is too long, before there are any optimizations on server side, I want to see if the code I wrote is optimized enough.

```
public class Scheduler {

    public Scheduler(AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    private Collection<CustomRequests> customRequests;

    public void initiateScheduler() {
        Long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(appConfig.concurrency);

        Generator generator = new Generator();
        customRequests = generator.generate();

        Long totalTimeReq = 0L;
        long maxTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        long minTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;

        Collection<Future<Long>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CustomRequest customRequest : customRequests) {
            futures.add(pool.submit(submitRequest(customRequests)));
        }

        try {
            for (Future f : futures) {
                while (f.isDone() == false) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Long time = (Long) f.get();
                totalTimeReq += time;
                maxTime = maxTime < time ? time : maxTime;
                minTime = minTime > time ? time : minTime;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while calculating responses");

        }

        log.info("Total time taken for WRs in ms {}", totalTimeReq);
        log.info("Total time taken: {} in ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - currTime);
        log.info("Avg time per req: {} in ms", totalTimeReq / customRequests.size());
        pool.shutdownNow();
    }

    private Callable submitRequest(CustomRequest customRequest) {
        return new Callable() {

            @Override
            public Long call() {

                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                long queryTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long doneTime = 0L;
                try {
                    //Create connection
                    URL url = new URL(appConfig.endpointUrl);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setCustomRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setCustomRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "application/x-protobuf");

                    connection.setCustomRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer " + appConfig.bearerToken);
                    connection.setCustomRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "snappy");
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    final SnappyOutputStream snappyOutputStream = new SnappyOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                    customRequest.writeTo(snappyOutputStream);
                    snappyOutputStream.close();

                    //Get Response
                    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    rd.close();
                    doneTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
                return (doneTime - queryTime);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated either on organization or optimizations.

Comment: Your requests seems getting paralleled , they are fine. Since you are holding for future, have you checked if the time is taken more for creating the requests or waiting for them? In case it is for waiting I would certainly put a timeout on my requests as well as on futures.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea, but instead of adding the futures to the list and executing them one by one, all you have to do is this, and you get a returned list of Future objects.

```
List<Callable<Long>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
for (CustomRequests request : customRequests)
    callables.add(submitRequest(request));

List<Future<Long>> results = pool.invokeAll(callables);
//Do as you wish with results
```

Comment: thanks for replying @Joe. Whats the advantage in doing that?

Comment: It executes whatever callable/runnable instances you give it, asynchronously (concurrently), the invokeAll method, spawns "worker" threads, with the max amount of concurrent jobs being preformed at once specified by "appConfig.concurrency" in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache Jmeter

https://jmeter.apache.org

Using jmeter you can generate concurrent load and max request etc

- https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/23/jmeter-rest-api-testing/

If you have any limitation not using tools then you can use Junit to genberate concurrent load for testing.

- https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-multithreaded-test-example/
- https://github.com/ThomasKrieger/concurrent-junit

Comment: I can't use Jmeter or any other existing tools due to some constraints.