# How to increase Http .execute performance

Tags: java, http

I have a list which contain lat and lng values
I just traverse this list fetching the lat and lng and find the weather report for particular Lat and lng
but it takes around 75 sec for 100 times.
how can I decrease this time

```
for(LatandlngList value:latandlngList)
{
   Double lat= value.getLat();
   Double lng= value.getLng();
   String URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng
             +"&appid="+appId;

HttpClient weatherClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet weatherReq=new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse weatherresult=weatherClient.execute(weatherReq);
}
```

The consider loop runs 100 time for finding weatherReport it takes around 75 second
how can I decrease this time

Comment: In addition to the answers, do all 100 lat/long points really need to be part of the loop?  For example, if the user is looking at a map and those points are not currently displayed, then is there is any value in the http request for that point that's not even visible?  Or perhaps the user is zoomed out on a map and some of the lat/long points are close to each other, so only need an http request on one of the points.  Or if the lat/long point is repeatedly called, then maybe it's acceptable to cache some results for a short period of time to avoid an unnecessary http call.

Answer (score 0):

Run them in parallel. You can't speed up a single request, its performance is determined by network latency and http-server response time. E.g. [here'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565332/how-to-send-parallel-http-post-requests-in-java#57565399)s a post that goes through the exercise for POSTs, but it applies for GETs as well.

Btw. you don't need a new HttpClient for each request, one for all will do. This may save you a little time, but nowhere near levels that make a difference.

Another classical issue when scraping data may be throttling by the server, which can be circumvented e.g. using [IP rotation](https://www.parsehub.com/blog/web-scraper-block-ip-rotation/), but that's a whole topic by itself.

Finally you can check for overlapping areas in your lat/long list to prevent multiple requests returning the same data. There's some headache about map projections used, but its definitely doable. I used the [JTS topology suite](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) once for such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reusing connections. Your example should not need a new HTTP client each time.
See: https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Few points to consider based on code-

1. If possible, create singleton `HttpClient`. In your code, you are creating `HttpClient` in every iterations-- which is not good idea.
   Once singleton is created, use it in your loop.
2. If sequential execution is not constraint, you can use parallel execution-- by using `Threads` or even by using `parallelStreams()`